# How can I gsub everything until the next empty line?

Tags: ruby, regex, markup, textile

Given this string:

```
bc.  some text
 more text
 even more

^ above here is the empty line
```

I want it to be:

```
<pre>
some text
more text
even more
</pre>

^ above here is the empty line
```

How can I regex for **"starting from `bc.` until the first empty line"**?

So far I got this:

```
# note that for some reason a direct .gsub! behaves
# differently/fails when using the block, so I use .gsub
textile_markup = textile_markup.gsub(/^bc.  .*^$/m) { |s| "<pre>#{s[5..(s.length)]}</pre>" }
```

Understandibly, this matches greedy until the very last empty line - instead of the first one.
**How can I make the ^$ part non-greedy?**

Comment: Usually `.*?` is the non-greedy version of `.*`. Would that work?

Comment: you will need the /s modifier for dot to match new lines

Comment: Do you have only one block, or is this a repeating pattern through the string/file? If it's repeating you need to represent that in your sample data. Also, why does this have to be done using a regular expression?

Comment: do you know this great site called rubular? http://rubular.com/r/uloTda090y

Comment: @theTinMan I only have one block. I am open to more efficient solutions also. However I think the shortest path will be a regex.

Comment: @phoet Thanks for the hint on the site. The example matcher however fails my sample code. See here: http://rubular.com/r/Tz5MuKg41z (sorry also for the confusion - I updated the sample to display the last string **after** the closing `</pre>`.

Comment: @user569825 there is no need to gsub the whole thing! use a matchgroup and then put everything where it belongs

Comment: @phoet I am having trouble understanding your proposed idea. Could you update the example you posted to reflect it?

Comment: @user569825 have a look at the docs http://apidock.com/ruby/String/match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = 
"bc.  some text
more text
even more

^ above here is the empty line

bc.  some text
more text
even more

^ above here is the empty line"

puts str.gsub(/^bc\.  (.*?)\n\n/m, "<pre>\n\\1\n</pre>\n\n")
```

Output:

```
<pre>
some text
more text
even more
</pre>

^ above here is the empty line

<pre>
some text
more text
even more
</pre>

^ above here is the empty line
```

#### Explanation

`?` in `.*?` makes the star operator non greedy

`/m` modifier in the end makes dot match newlines

Comment: On the documents I tested so far work great with that code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one go, but it needs some preparation:

```
txt = <<DOC
bc.  some text
 more text
 even more

bc.  some text
 more text
 even more

DOC

TRANSFORMS = {"bc.  " => "<pre>\n",       # The 'bc.  should become <pre> followed by a line-end
              /^ /    => "",              # leading space should be eliminated
             "\n\n"   => "\n<\/pre>\n\n"} # empty line should be preceded by a closing pre-tag

re = Regexp.union(TRANSFORMS.keys)
puts txt.gsub(re, TRANSFORMS)
```

Output:

```
<pre>
some text
more text
even more
</pre>

<pre>
some text
more text
even more
</pre>
```

Comment: I absolutely like the way you coded that! The substitutions apply in other situations as well, which I want to avoid as I am working on huge documents. Yuriy Golobokov's `gsub` variant works and I think it'd be interesting for everyone to see it using your style, if possible. Would be great if you'd update.

Comment: It will add `"\n<\/pre>\n\n"` for every empty line even if paragraph wasn't started with `bc. `